# Intel HD Graphics card not recognized in System Info

Tags: intel-graphics, system-info

When I check the info of my laptop, it shows me "Graphics Unknown":

[image]

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that it cannot acquire the information because `glxinfo` is not installed on the system.

You can install mesa-utils with the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or by typing in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Answer (score 0):

Issued filed on launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/888141