# Install Intel HD graphics

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics

I have just installed ubuntu 11.10 on my PB EasyNote TK i3. I now want to install driver for the Intel HD Graphics to have a better resolution but I don't know how to do that.
Thanks

Comment: If is an intel hd card please look at this thread.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/73074/intel-hd-graphics-card-not-recognized-in-system-info

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install drivers for an Intel HD Graphics?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87090/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-an-intel-hd-graphics)

Answer (score 2):

the kernel has drivers installed by default for intel gfx

go to system settings>system info
then click on graphics there you'll see ur graphics driver are installed

[image]

Comment: I think it also has something to do with being online. My laptop has Intel graphics but it was initially listed as unknown graphics under System Info. However, after running updates one day the graphics were noticeably more responsive and were also listed correctly under System Info.

Comment: This panel tells me that my graphics is unknown :(

Comment: OK maybe it will be added after some updated

Comment: yeah may be also mine wasnt detected in the LIVE version be it from cd or liveusb, after installation it shows up

Comment: Here is your answer: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-intel-integrated-graphics-to-be-recognized-in-system-info) it is a bug and you need to install mesa manually

Answer (score 0):

Go to the intel linux webpage : https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads

Get the Intel(R) Graphics Installer for Linux* 1.0.x and install the package.
Once installed, run `sudo intel-linux-graphics-installer` and follow the steps of the graphical installer