# How do I install drivers for an Intel HD Graphics?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

In System Info in 11.10, the graphics driver wasn't detected. I use ACER Aspire 4750 with Intel Core i3-2340M and Intel HD Graphics 3000 graphic card

How to install the driver for my Ubuntu?

Comment: go to the [Intel Linux Graphics](http://intellinuxgraphics.org/) website. This is the original Intel website and not a third-party. Look around and see what You can find. And here is the [link](http://intellinuxgraphics.org/2011Q4.html) for the latest driver available.

Answer (score 25):

The Intel cards are automatically detected and installed in Ubuntu, no need to install further drivers. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-intel-integrated-graphics-to-be-recognized-in-system-info) if you want them to be recognised in System Info.

---

However, if you feel that you want to install a more recent driver (I dont recommend this if you do not know how to recover from a broken graphics driver) you can add the [xorg-edgers fresh X crack PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers) and update your system with the packages from there.

To do that open a terminal and use these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Reboot with

```
sudo reboot
```

Again, **do this only this with extra caution**!

Answer (score 21):

If you don't want the bleeding edge in drivers, you can also use the x-swat PPA, which contains more stable drives.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: This is a more appropriate answer for most people I think.

Comment: Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages  404  Not Found - any fix?

Comment: PPA link is now `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates`.

Answer (score 3):

The [Intel Graphics Update Tool for Linux](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2)<sup>(*)</sup> allows you to easily install the latest graphics and video drivers for your Intel graphics hardware. This allows you to stay current with the latest enhancements, optimizations, and fixes to the Intel Graphics Stack to ensure the best user experience with your Intel graphics hardware. The Intel Graphics Update Tool for Linux was available for the latest LTS version of Ubuntu at the time this answer was posted.

Thanks to [Shahe Tajiryan](https://askubuntu.com/users/27236/shahe-tajiryan).

<sup>(*)</sup>: [Intel Graphics Update Tool for Linux is discontinued](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/update-tool)

Comment: After update with this tool my screen on external monitor is blinking from time to time (turning black for about 3 seconds every 15 minutes) :( Drivers installed in Ubuntu by default were better.