# How Do I Install Intel HD Graphics Driver on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my Intel integrated graphics to be recognized in System Info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-intel-integrated-graphics-to-be-recognized-in-system-info)
>   [How do I install drivers for an Intel HD Graphics?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87090/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-an-intel-hd-graphics)

How do i install intel hd graphics driver on ubuntu 12.04? I'm a beginner ubuntu user, so i could not install drivers.

Comment: I don't think that question makes sense. Please edit the question and title to ask about the problem you are having, rather than what you think the solution might be. For example is it that you cannot play a particular type of DVD? Don't reply to this with another comment, but edit the question.

Comment: It should be installed by default. Are you facing any graphics issues ?