# Graphics card is not recognized in System info

Tags: graphics

My graphics card is not recognized in system info, It is an onboard GMA 965gm (or x3100), but i can still play games which require 3D acceleration. How can i correctly install the drivers?

Thank you

EDIT: It runs on ubu 12.04

After running the lspci -v command it came up with the following 
The os is 12.04.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device 00a1
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at 90100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 6110 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: intelfb, i915


00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device 00a1
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at 90200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: < access denied >
```

It seems to my noob eyes that the card is recognised, but it doesnt show up in system settings nor in the additional drivers.

Comment: Your system info question will be resolved by this Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-intel-integrated-graphics-to-be-recognized-in-system-info

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Thomas! Run "*Additional Drivers*" and install the one recommended and reboot your Ubuntu.It may help you.

Comment: Great idea.I have already done that Beeju but unfortunately, it didnt come up with any additional drivers apart from my wireless card.

Comment: Pls include more specification about your system and Ubuntu version.Could u pls include the image of "Additional drivers" application? Type lspci -v in terminal and give the output of your video card here.

Answer (score 0):

Intel i915 driver module, which should recognise your graphics chipset, should be loaded in kernel by default. Probably that's why it's not listed in Additional driver.

What is the output of the command `lsmod | grep i915`? If it's returning i915 that means the module is already loaded and working.

If not then open `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and check if the kernel line (the line which is started with `linux /boot/vmlinuz..`) has the parameter `i915.modeset=1`. If not or if the line has parameter `nomodeset` then open `/etc/default/grub` and edit the following line as

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.modeset=1"` then reboot. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

try installing

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

this fixed it for me with a slightly different onboard graphics card, but I believe it's universal. You can always remove it!

```
sudo apt-get purge mesa-utils
```

source

[How Do I Install Intel HD Graphics Driver on Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129227/how-do-i-install-intel-hd-graphics-driver-on-ubuntu-12-04)