# Intel HD graphic card installation

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 it's missing Intel HD graphics card.

How can I install it from terminal?

Comment: Can you please paste the output of the following command? lspci

Comment: My understanding is that there is no such thing as an Intel graphics adapter. All Intel graphics are integrated into the motherboard or, these days, onto the same die as the CPU. What problems are you having which prompted you to ask for a driver (?) for Intel integrated graphics? What Intel hardware are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install drivers for an Intel HD Graphics?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87090/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-an-intel-hd-graphics)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu is supporting any VGA cards,but sometime it doesn't list them in "system setting",
You should try to install **mesa-utils**.
From the Software Center :

[image: Install via the software center]

Or install it from terminal :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Or if this can't find in your repository list, go to http://apt-web.dahsy.at
and then choose your ubuntu version (or select the latest version in the list) according your OS Architecture (64bit/32bit{i836}). and type `mesa-utils`. Download the file and type on terminal :

```
sudo dpkg -i location-of-downloaded-file/Package-name.deb
```

And replace the bold text with the location and name of the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest drivers for your kernel from intel opensource projects website : https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads

Get the linux installer, install it then run `intel-linux-graphics-installer`