# Intel I945GMS driver for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, graphics, laptop, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install drivers for an Intel HD Graphics?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87090/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-an-intel-hd-graphics)

I can't find the proprietary driver of Intel I945GMS for Ubuntu 12.04! Does it exist for Intel i945gms notebook integrated video?

Comment: What do you mean by 'proper driver'? As for your info, Ubuntu is a Linux distro, and there is no special driver just for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same card here using the 32-bit version of 12.04 and it is working out of the box. Here's the output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
```

Are you having issues with the card or just wanting to install the Intel driver over the default one?