# I can't change my screen resolution

Tags: resolution, screen

I am newer to Ubuntu. Recently I bought Intel® Core™ i3-2120 CPU @ 3.30GHz (Intel HD Graphics 2000 display) with Dell IN2030M monitor. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS version. My problem is, I can't change my screen resolution >1024 because the monitor was not detected, it says Unknown. Help please.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install at least the package mesa-utils.

On a console type:

`sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

Logout and login

That will give you the basic graphic drivers, for advanced graphics you need to install Intel HD Graphics.

This has already been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85318/how-can-i-get-my-intel-integrated-graphics-to-be-recognized-in-system-info) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87090/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-an-intel-hd-graphics)