# Ubuntu has wrong resolution and won't let me change it

Tags: display

Ubuntu 15.04 x64 gives me 800x600 when my screen can output 1600x900. I went into my display settings and there was only one option. Anything I can do to fix it?
    lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
Outputs

```
VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini
```

[Radeon HD 8240 / R3 Series]
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 083a
Kernal driver in use: fglrx_pci

Sorry for formatting issues

Comment: you may check for the display driver updates.

Comment: @kashminder It was working fine yesterday then I booted it this morning and it was that resolution. I went into additional drivers and it had automatically set to manually installed driver and it would not let me change anything.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command. And specify the Ubuntu version.

Answer (score -1):

Run

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

in terminal.This should hep you to change to correct resolution.
In case your drivers are not upto date , try installing proprietary drivers from the Software and Updates section of ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: mesa-utils have nothing to do with resolution.

Comment: I had similar problem. Installing mesa-utils solved it.

Comment: @Pilot6 why are you so sure?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I seem to know what exactly `mesa-utils` installs ;-) It can't improve anything. You can look yourself.

Comment: @Pilot6 it helped other person ;-)

Comment: Take a look http://askubuntu.com/questions/190488/i-cant-change-my-screen-resolution

Comment: There is no evidence that it helped anyone in the other question. And it is impossible anyway.