# Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS fails to find Intel HD Graphics 3000 and video playing error

Tags: graphics, intel, toshiba

hello i'm new to linux

i'm using Toshiba c850 notebook and i can't install ' intel HD graphics 3000 ' driver on ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (32 bit)

the problem is when i play HD movies , video is not smoothly playing. and every time i boot up my notebook on ubuntu i have to adjust my screen brightness.it goes maximum level every time i restart my notebook.but in windows it works fine and HD videos play smoothly.

please help friends.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to askubuntu. To get helpful answer you need to follow few points,

- First thing, you should not club many question at one question. Read [FAQ]
- Second thing, post hardware details as much as possible. We don't own the device. Google search will reveal many model with the same name.
- Last, search before you post.

Back to answers

a) Intel Grpahics card drivers are open sourced and in inbuilt in kernel. So ubuntu doesn't require installation of these driver. Run `dpkg -s xserver-xorg-video-intel` to check the status of the driver package: it should be installed.

b) brightness issue:

1. If your brigtness key not working . try following else **skip to step 2**

   execute `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

   Change this line

   `GRUB_CMLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

   to something like below

   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"`

   Execute `sudo update-grub` and reboot . See if brightness keys are working.
2. It is still possible ubuntu won't remember your brightness settings. So you have to change brightness each time.

   Try following for paths shown by `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` and replace accordingly.

   example paths will be like

   /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

   1. For the above path Get the maximum brightness:

   `cat  /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness`

   Try a lower value to set the brightness, say output is 16 so I will try with half of it

   `echo 8 | sudo tee  /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`

   **If this works**,  make this happen in each login automatically by doing the following

   `sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`

   Enter this line just before `exit 0`. It should look like

   echo YOUR_VALUE_HERE > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
   exit 0
3. HD video issue. Try a different player like vlc. If the problem is there you may want to update drivers from `xorg-edgers` ppa. **Though generally it doesn't require & intel HD can play HD videos without any extra update**. See [How do I install drivers for an Intel HD Graphics?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87090/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-an-intel-hd-graphics)

Comment: thanks for your help.brightness issue is now ok.but Intel HD Graphics issue is still there.i tried using VLC and Totem Movie player.and i xorg drivers using these commands    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade but issue is still there.

Comment: i installed xrog drivers* using these --> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade