# resolved - Unable to run Live CD Ubuntu 13:04 on Acer Aspire M5 481T 6417. Is there any video driver incompatibility?

Tags: installation, drivers, screen, acer, aspire

I made the purchase of this notebook with the thought of installing Ubuntu. However, it was not successful in my attempts. I've done searches on google and other forums that discuss Ubuntu. Found that staff had dificudades with the new UEFI, but sufficed some settings and succeeded.
My case is different, put the pendriver to install, start grub select to use without installing after that the screen is all black, but the light of pendriver is at work and after a while this situation behold hear the traditional drums stating that system is increased and at login. But the screen is still black invalidating anything.
So this is my question: anyone experienced the same difivuldade and managed to install ubuntu on this laptop?
I've changed the bios to legacy, already formatted the pendriver in MTR and GPT and always the same thing. If they can give direction I am grateful.

thank you

Comment: Did you try the option "nomodeset" (F6) at the Try/Install screen?  Once running, you can tell us your video hardware -- there might be proprietary drivers to install to improve things.

Comment: I don't think it's video: "Intel Grpahics card drivers are open sourced and in inbuilt in kernel. So ubuntu doesn't require installation of these driver. Run dpkg -s xserver-xorg-video-intel to check the status of the driver package: it should be installed."  http://askubuntu.com/questions/232275/ubuntu-12-04-1-lts-fails-to-find-intel-hd-graphics-3000-and-video-playing-error

Comment: Hello ubfan1 and Marc!
Thanks for helping me on this!
Now the answers:

1 - ubfan1, when I'm on the screen to choose options (GRUB2) tightening the F6 button but nothing happens. The video card is an Intel (R) HD Graphics 4000 128 MB (Seen in the windows device manager).

2 - Marc, that link you provided me the person was able to install and has a problem in HD movies. In my case the only thing I can do and get the GRUB2 or tightening the letter "e" to type some commands or enter the option. After this all black.

Comment: Dear used the 12:04. Went and got the GRUB screen to X. Well wanted to use the newest, but it's worth. Now go to the next stage, to operate the peripherals.

Thank you!

Comment: I have not spoken version that was trying to use. The problem was with the 64-bit Raring Ringtail 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Brazilian. I do not speak English, but I'm trying to explain to you ... My notebook is Acer Aspire 6417 M5 481T also, I had put more shine with the combination of buttons: "Fn + (Right Arrow)" and it worked .. I have helped you ...