# Getting black on team fotress 2 using linux version of steam

Tags: steam

I have 12.04 64 bit installed and I am trying out steam for Ubuntu. When I installed Team Fortress 2 and try to start it, I get a black screen with only audio you can hear. I have 4gigs of RAM, Intel Graphics 3000 card, and icore3 CPU. I installed the new drivers from Ubuntu wiki with the instruction to install steam. Apparently the drivers will not install or they are listed as unknown. How do I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have privileges to comment so I'm going to post this as an answer:
What driver is selected when you go to Dash and then type Additional drivers:
one graphics driver should be highlighted.  Also it appears this may help you:
[How do I install drivers for an Intel HD Graphics?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87090/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-an-intel-hd-graphics)

Comment: No drivers are displayed when I search for additional drivers.