# Error while installing Addtional drivers?

Tags: drivers

I am trying to install additional drivers on Ubuntu 12.04. The application is returning an error. In the log file I can see various NVIDIA module failed to load. However, my PC do not have NVIDIA graphics card. Its Intel card, then why is Ubuntu searching for NVIDIA card?

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 and additional drivers before without any error.

Though this is the first time I am using Windows installer version. I don't know if its related to that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to purge ur nvidia driver card, go to terminal. and type: sudo apt-get purge nvidia* [enter] and sudo apt-get purge nouveau* [enter]

If u sure ur card is intel please check this out. [How do I install drivers for an Intel HD Graphics?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87090/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-an-intel-hd-graphics) , i hope this link will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to upgrade your Linux kernel and X stack to the Ubuntu 12.10 versions. These have more up to date hardware and driver support.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-quantal xserver-xorg-lts-quantal
```

This may sound like an experimental thing to do — you are on an LTS release for a reason — but has actually become standard policy with the latest point release (12.04.2) of Precise on 14 February. Read [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) for more information.

The LTS Enablement Stack is enabled by default in fresh installs of 12.04.2, but needs to be explicitly activated in systems upgrading from 12.04 or 12.04.1. Installing the packages **linux-generic-lts-quantal** and/or **xserver-xorg-lts-quantal** will do just that.