# Red vertical lines in text

Tags: 18.04, fonts

I've made some strange experiences ever since I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04: Small vertical red lines are occuring next to (random) letters in almost every word that is displayed in any program. This is kind of annoying, since it renders a text hard to read. Changing of fonts does not help. Does anyone know what might cause this problem and could give me a hint regarding a possible solution?

I would highly appreciate that.

[image: Red vertical lines next to letters]

Comment: What driver are you using for the videocard?  You might get better results switching to or from the open source from the proprietary version. If that is possible What make/model is it?

Comment: It's a Lenovo Ideapad 500s-14isk with low specs, i.e. Intel® Core™ i3-6100U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4, Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) and 3 GB DDR3.
As for the drive the Ubuntu installation came with i915, which seems to be proprietary. I am not aware of other drivers, but I would be thankful if you could name me some :)

Comment: @Rinzwind: Thank you for your suggestion.
I added a PPA according to this post

https://askubuntu.com/questions/87090/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-an-intel-hd-graphics?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

and this resolved my problem.

Comment: Cool! Please answer you own question :) and accept it when the grace period has passed.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the advice of Rinzwind and tried alternative drivers according to this thread:

https://askubuntu.com/a/87094/837925

As for me, this resolved my problem.