# Screen flickering as I type

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, intel-graphics

I have laptop with 18.04 installed, this problem also occurred when I used 16.04 before.

My screen seems to blink when I start typing, it blinked instantly that I could not capture the moment of it, anyhow the blinking also happens randomly, there is no pattern at all.

I have tried the suggestion from various source, this includes:

1. Updating the kernel, I am using kernel 4.19 now, before this I was using kernel 4.5 or 4.6 but does not work also.
2. Updating graphics driver, running command from https://askubuntu.com/a/215967. Doesn't seem to work, the flickering still happens.

How do I stop this from happening, it is not really distracting because it's only fraction of second, but if I can stop it I rather do so.

I don't have dedicated video graphics card, using Intel graphics at the moment. I think it's Intel HD 3000.

`sudo lshw -C video | grep product` result.

```
sudo lshw -C video | grep product
product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
```

`uname -r` result.

```
$ uname -r
4.19.20-041920-generic
```

If you want further command, I'd love to include them.

Ridgwell

Comment: It seems it's a hardware problem. That's what I could infer from your description.

Comment: Seconded. Looks like a hardware problem. Might be a loose connector or your screen might be about to go. Or worst case, its the inbuilt gpu, in which case toss the motherboard.

Comment: Do you have an ambient light sensor on your laptop ? Maybe the driver isn't responding correctly to light changes due to your hands...

Comment: Are you certain that this isn't a hardware related problem? There are a lot of modern laptops out there that suffer this exact problem. Commonly it's associated with PWM for the screen below a certain brightness threshold. Please describe what it looks like. Is it a sort of immediate on/off-like thing or does it look like the cable to the screen is coming loose?

Comment: any update on your issue, OP?

Comment: Probably hardware problem, I took it to computer repair service and it seems I don't have this problem anymore.