# How to get intel 82845 graphic drivers for ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, video, intel-graphics

When I had XP, after installing it, I used to run the setup.exe file for graphic driver. This used to greatly improve graphic quality, like good looking small icons, cleaner videos, and so on. Now, for Ubuntu too, there must be a similar graphic driver, maybe provided by intel, (a counterpart of "setup.exe" for ubuntu), which would improve graphic quality just like in windows. Trouble was I could never find one. Need help.

BTW in xp I needed sound driver too, to enable sound. I don't need anything for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you installed Ubuntu 11.10.

The last sentence of your questions tells all you need to know: ***You dont need anything for Ubuntu*** (not in your case anyways).

Intel has been one of the companies supplying the open-source community with good support, their drivers are already included in the packages of most Linux distros.

You dont need any graphics drivers to install in your system. Just update it, thats is enough.

Comment: I did update it. But as I said before I couldn't get the cool icons and stuff. The icons are big and graphic quality is rusty. It is the same as it is after installing windows xp but before installing the intel graphic drivers.

Comment: Can you please add an screen shot to the question so we can better see what is happening?

Comment: Please See This Link http://askubuntu.com/questions/95440/how-do-i-know-whether-ubuntu-has-in-built-drivers-for-82845-graphic-controller-a

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer at

[Intel HD Graphics card not recognized in System Info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73074/intel-hd-graphics-card-not-recognized-in-system-info)

It helped me with a different but albeit similar problem of Ubuntu not picking up an Intel graphics card

When I did this then the relevant info appeared

> sudo apt-get install mesa-utils