# How do I know whether Ubuntu has in-built drivers for 82845 graphic controller and how to get it if it isn't?

Tags: intel-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get intel 82845 graphic drivers for ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94443/how-to-get-intel-82845-graphic-drivers-for-ubuntu)

I was not sure I had right graphic driver installed as the graphic quality was not as good as that in windows. This is a screenshot of my desktop under windows.[image]

And this one is how it looks under Ubuntu [image]

So I downloaded some installation packages from intel. One was a .rpm file the other was .tar.gz file. I installed the .rpm file using alien but could see no changes, the graphic quality remained the same.
Then I tried compiling the .tar.gz file. I extracted it and then ran the ./configure command. Error- No such file or directory. When I ran the make command, error- No target specified and no makefile found. Then I simply ran the sudo ./install.sh command.
Error- the dri drivers cannot be installed without the lates kernel modules.

I really want the graphics in Ubuntu to look as good as that. I am not even sure whether Ubuntu already has the required drivers but if it does why are the graphics so rusty, and if not why am I unable to install the drivers provided by intel? Please help.
This is the link from where I downloaded the drivers. [Here.](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Desktop%20graphics%20controllers&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%2082845G%20Graphics%20Controller&OSVersion=Linux*&DownloadType=Drivers)

Comment: There is. Please look at your other question answers http://askubuntu.com/a/94446/7567

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about screen resolution? Icon size? Background image positioning?

Those should be configurable, you should check on your display settings and appearance as well. Look for them on your System menu.

The Intel graphic driver is [already installed](https://askubuntu.com/a/94446/28076), so it is not really the problem.

Comment: The highest screen resolution in xp is 1366x768. But in Ubuntu it is 1026x768. I checked it in screen resolution. So the only explanation is that I don't have correct drivers installed.

Comment: If it's a resolution issue, here you go: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37411/screen-resolution-stuck-at-1024x768
Stop asking if there are intel drivers in ubuntu because the answer is yes and it's open source only so nothing to download and install.

Comment: @YasserHussain have you tried to run the latest Ubuntu release? Your issue could be related to that, like mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you are using the Lucid Linyx 10.04 LTS release of Ubuntu.

The newer releases are in general, a lot prettier than this release.

Other than that, is your issue with the scaling of your wallpaper? Or something else? Is it just because the screen sizes and aspect ratios of these screenshots are different? Are you looking at the two OSs on different screens (with different quality)?

If it's fonts, you may want to configure the anti-aliasing (the font config panel was still available in this release).

(On Windows, your wallpaper looks much worse, to my eye, because it has been stretched out of it's normal aspect ratio)