# Ubuntu driver for Intel Sandybridge/Ivybridge Graphics

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, intel, drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install drivers for an Intel HD Graphics?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87090/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-an-intel-hd-graphics)

I have installed Edubuntu 11.10 on a HP Pro 3420 All-in-One PC (CPU G630, 64 bit). Initially I couldn't get any display at all. Then I searched on internet an applied the trick of adding the option i915.modeset=0 on the boot menu. Now I can see the display, but it is only a VESA graphic driver, and the display is really coarse and ugly. I have also tried to install the glasen/intel-driver (and removed the option i915.modeset=0), but I couldn't get the display.
Does anybody know where to find the proper graphics driver and how to install it?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this post is related to your issue.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/73074/intel-hd-graphics-card-not-recognized-in-system-info

Comment: Perhaps this might help for you also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124640/how-to-upgrade-intel-graphics-package-to-the-12-02-release/125197#125197