# Ubuntu doesn't recognize Intel HD graphics 3000

Tags: 12.04, intel, macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Intel HD Graphics card not recognized in System Info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73074/intel-hd-graphics-card-not-recognized-in-system-info)

I have ubuntu installed on a MacBook Pro 8.1 and it doesn't recognize my graphics card (Intel HD Graphics 3000) and i want to know why is this happening and how to make that Ubuntu recognizes my graphics card.
Plus, if someone knows how to enable the subwoofer on the OS i wpuld thank you very much.

Comment: Are you not getting any display at all?  Do you have garbled video?

Comment: For the graphics question see the link above. for subwoofer question i suggest you to ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Install Mesa-Utils by running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Then it will be detected.